# Why can't I delete an event?

Tags: civievent

We have an event that will not delete. When trying to delete, the system gives:

"This event cannot be deleted because there are participant records linked to it. If you want to delete this event, you must first find the participants linked to this event and delete them. You can use use CiviEvent >> Find Participants page ."

There are no participants registered for this event. This happens every so often.

Comment: Perhaps you have is_test particpants?

Comment: You can make use of advanced search, i think it will help ?

Comment: @KarinG that would make a good answer, combined with a brief explanation of how to find them.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have is_test participants?

Events -> Find Participants
Participant is a test? Hit the Yes radio button
Search

If you have any - then select the participants you found - and then in the actions: delete participants.